# flash notification not working after following devise installation

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, devise

I followed the One Month Rails tutorial and at one point in the tutorial I was told to add this the following lines to my application.html.erb to enable flash messages

```
<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
    <%= content_tag(:div, msg, class: "alert alert-#{name}") %>
<%end%>
```

What this will do is it will display messages after logging in or logging out with some CSS styles around them .

When I followed along with the tutorial the code works fine, but when I try to start my own project, it no longer has the CSS styling around it. The message will still appear, but it'll just be plain text on the top of the page.

The following is my application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>JMO</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

    <div class = "container">
        <% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
                <%= content_tag(:div, msg, class: "alert alert-#{name}") %>
        <%end%>

        <%= render "layouts/header" %>

        <div class = "text-center">
            <%= yield %>
        </div>

        <%= render "layouts/footer" %>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the application.html.erb that was taken from the tutorial (the working version)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Omrails</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>

<body>
    <div class = "container">
        <!---require for devise setup step 3-->
        <% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
            <%= content_tag(:div, msg, class: "alert alert-#{name}") %>
        <%end%>
        <!---render header partial from layouts/header-->
        <%= render "layouts/header" %>
        <%= yield %>
        <!---render footer partial from layouts/header-->
    </div>
    <%= render "layouts/footer" %>
</body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Edit: I replaced my non-working file with the working file and see that the message now has no styling, so I am thinking the problem is not within my application.html.erb. Where else can the problem be? I am thinking this is a devise problem possibly?

Comment: Do I get your question correctly: you do see the message, your problem is that the styling has gone away?

Comment: Yeah, I see the message but there are no styling. In the working version, the message is wrapped in a yellow rounded rectangle. Sorry if I am unclear in my question

Comment: Then you have analyzed your own problem correctly: you have to add proper CSS rules in order to get the message styled again.

Comment: I looked into my CSS file and didn't find anything that is relatable. When I added the code in the working version, it magically works without any external CSS. The video didn't explain those lines of code either so I am not entire sure what they mean

Comment: Does **any** Bootstrap element render correctly?

Comment: Yes, I've used some nav function and container function and they all render correctly

Comment: To debug CSS problems your best bet is to use the element inspector of your browser. E.g. for Firefox or Chrome, right click the plain text of your flash message and choose 'Inspect' (might be called differently in your locale). You can then inspect in detail which CSS rules are applied

Answer (score 0):

To get the styles applied on HTML elements they must be defined somewhere by either adding your own styles or using an external css library.

As far as I know, OneMonthRails Tutorial uses [bootstrap-sass gem](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass) for styling purposes.

In order to get the same styling in your new Rails application, you need to do add the gem to your `Gemfile`

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
```

Run `bundle install` to install the gem.

Import `bootstrap` in `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss` file by adding following statement in it:

```
@import 'bootstrap';
```

and restart the server.

Comment: I did use the bootstrap-sass gem and also included the @import "bootstrap" in my custom.css.scss.

Comment: If that is the case then make sure that you have ` *= require_tree .` in `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css` and the `custom.css.scss` is placed under `app/assets/stylesheets` directory. The server must be restarted for the changes to take effect.

Comment: Yeah I have both of them already in place. This  is a really weird problem.. do you know what is the purpose of the alert and alsert#{name}?

Comment: Did you restart the server? alert and alert-#{name} are css classes for which styles are defined in bootstrap.

Comment: Yes I did also restart my server